# Stopping registration if email already exists in database

Tags: php, sql, redirect, registration

I'm practicing with PHP and SQL. I have a registering form, and I want to stop users from being able to register on my website if their email is already registered. My code doesn't do it, and I still can't see my error. Can someone help me please? This is my php file.

```
$sql_user_name = "root";  //PHPMYADMIN INFORMATIONS
$sql_password = "";
$sql_database = "registeredusers";
$sql_table = "registeredusers";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysqli_connect($server, $sql_user_name, $sql_password);  //CONNECTION TO DATABASE
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle,$sql_database);  //OPENING TABLE

$email_exists = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $sql_table WHERE email = '$email'");

if ($db_found && mysqli_num_rows($email_exists) > 0) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo "Email is already registered.";
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
}
else if ($db_found) {  //WRITES INTO DATABASE IF TABLE HAS SUCCESSFULLY BEEN OPENED AND EMAIL ISN'T IN USE
        $SQL = mysqli_query($db_handle,"INSERT INTO registeredusers (name, email, password, gender, birthday)
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$gender', '$birthday')");

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Welcome to Sketchule";
        $message = "Hello! Welcome to Sketchule!";
        $from = "lpb.baillargeon@gmail.com";
        $headers = "From: $from";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mysqli_close($db_handle);
        header('Location: confirmation.php');
    }
else {  //FINISHED CONNECTION IF OPERATION UNSUCCESSFUL
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
}
```

Update:

It never goes into this part of the script:

```
    if ($db_found && mysqli_num_rows($email_exists) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['registered'];
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

It never redirects me to index.php, and it still sends an email.

Update: this is how I got it to work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM registeredusers WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db_handle));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['registered'] = "Email is already registered.";
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
else {  //WRITES INTO DATABASE IF TABLE HAS SUCCESSFULLY BEEN OPENED AND EMAIL ISN'T IN USE
        $SQL = mysqli_query($db_handle,"INSERT INTO registeredusers (name, email, password, gender, birthday)
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$gender', '$birthday')");

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Welcome to Sketchule";
        $message = "Hello! Welcome to Sketchule!";
        $from = "lpb.baillargeon@gmail.com";
        $headers = "From: $from";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mysqli_close($db_handle);
        header('Location: confirmation.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot see the echo, because of the redirection

Comment: While I would still advise validating as you are doing to prevent duplicates, you should also constrain the email column to be unique to prevent duplicates.

Comment: must use, `exit();` after `header()`

Comment: So if I understand well, I need to put the echo on index.php? Is there a way to know where the user comes from? So if I know he has been redirected from this script, I am able to echo this error?

Also, I constrained the email column to be unique on phpMyAdmin. Is this enough, or do I need to add something to the php file?

Thanks

Comment: Please reduce your code-example to the *bare minimum* needed to reproduce your issue. This is done by writing the example from scratch with as little code as necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Better way is that you need to store message in `SESSION` and then echo it on redirected page, also must use `exit()` after `header()`...

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($email_exists) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Email is already registered.";
    http_redirect('index.php', [], TRUE);
}
```

then on index.php

```
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
```

Comment: -1 for the misleading comment that `echo` would not be possible after `header()` which is not only wrong but also plainly misguiding as it is recommended to echo after location header.

Comment: The recommended echo after the header is still missing. Also you should use fully qualified URI with the location header.

Comment: I'm fairly new with all of this. index.php is where the HTML form is coded. The form is set to POST in validate, which contains the code in my question. After editing index.php and validate.php to what you suggested, it now tells me that _SESSION is an undefined variable when I am on index.php

Any insight on that? Thanks.

Comment: you need to start session on the top of the index.php file.. `session_start();`

Comment: I still had an error, but I changed my script to this:

session_start();
if ($_SESSION != NULL){
$error = $_SESSION['registered'];
echo $error;     
}

And it seems to work now. Only part that still doesn't work is, I don't get redirected to index.php.

I'll update my question so it can be more clear

Comment: where you have defined your `$email` variable?

Comment: I have defined $email in the same file, with this code: $email = $_POST[trim('email')];

In index.php, the email field has the name="email" attribute

Answer (score 3):

In the database, make the email id column UNIQUE. This should solve it. Create a corresponding error message along with it when someone try to register with the same id.

Answer (score 2):

The `header('Location: index.php');` statement redirects your page before `echo "Email is already registered.";` is processed.

So in order to see the error message being displayed redirect to some other page Like `header('Location: error.php');` where `error.php` displays the error message or else remove the `header('Location: index.php');` statement

Answer (score 1):

Remove header() function after the echo and your message will be visible.

`if ($db_found && mysqli_num_rows($email_exists) > 0) {

```
echo "Email is already registered.";
mysqli_close($db_handle);
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$email_exists = mysqli_query=("select email from $sql_table where email='$email'");
```

The outcome of this should just be the inserted email.

sorry
**EDIT:**

It should be like this I think:

```
$check=$email_exists->num_rows;

if($check==0){
//email doesn't exist
}
else{
//email does exist
}
```

please let me know if it works.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeBaillargeon Was it a solution provided by one the people who answered? If so, please accept an answer. Thank you